# ReferenceError: $state is not defined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a rails application which use AngularJS and I have a problem, the problem is that I want redirect to a certain `state` after a form is submited, but in the chrome's console I have a `ReferenceError: $state is not defined` and nothing happens.

[image: state error]

This is my controller.

```
angular.module('myapp')

.controller('CreatePollCtrl', ['$scope', 'Restangular', '$state',
function($scope, Restangular) {

  $scope.addPoll = function() {
    if ($scope.allow_anonymous_answer == null)
      $scope.allow_anonymous_answer = false

    var poll = {title: $scope.title, description: $scope.description, allow_anonymous_answer: $scope.allow_anonymous_answer, initial_message: $scope.initial_message, final_message: $scope.final_message};
    Restangular.all('polls').post(poll).then(function(response) {
      $state.go('dashboard');
    });
  };
}]);
```

What can I do?, is `$state` correctly injected?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you forgot add `$state` to `function()`

```
angular.module('myapp')

.controller('CreatePollCtrl', ['$scope', 'Restangular', '$state',
function($scope, Restangular, $state) {
```

Comment: LOL, I think I tried that, but didn't work, I think I should have reset the server to work...

Answer (score 3):

Add `$state` as a parameter to your function, like `$scope.addPoll = function($state) {...}`