# AngularJS - Multistep form with UI Router and Navigate using arrow keys

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, multi-step

How do I go to next or previous form step using arrow key. I'm using AngularJS UI Router. The code below working fine with prev and next button to navigate.

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider    
        // route to show our basic form (/form)
        .state('wsp', {
            url: '/wsp',
            templateUrl: 'wsp_step',
            controller: 'wspYearController'
        })

        .state('wsp.first_step', {
            url: '/first_step',
            templateUrl: 'wsp_step_first'
        })

        .state('wsp.second_step', {
            url: '/second_step',
            templateUrl: 'wsp_step_second'
        })


    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/wsp/first_step');
})
```

To go to different step I am doing like this

```
<button type="button" ui-sref="wsp.first_step">Prev </button>
<button type="button" ui-sref="wsp.third_step">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are. A `keydown event listener` with self handling event unbinding and bind before/after `$stateChange`. `ng-keydown` will not help you here =(. Lets hope keyhandling will be improved in AngularJS. You should be fine by adding this into your `wspYearController` (if its used in all the routes you talking about).

```
/**
 * Key press binding
 */
$(document).keydown(function(e) {

    switch(e.which) {
        case 37: // left arrow
        case 39: // right arrow

            //clean listener before state change 
            //else it would be listen all the time :)
            $(document).unbind('keydown');

            //back and forward all the time to the right place.
            if ($state.current.name === 'wsp.first_step') {
                $state.go('wsp.second_step');
            } else {
                $state.go('wsp.first_step');
            }
            break;

        default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }

    // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Here is a [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/tlO764Bm1nw9uecDKlLr/) which shows you a demonstration of it.

Comment: This does not work based on which key is pressed. You have to separate left and right arrow.

Comment: Sure it does and its included right now. You want a working example @PaulsonPeter ?

Comment: could you please provide working example as i am getting '$state is not defined' error

Comment: Are you parsing `$state` to your controller? This is a AngularJS basic, check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35022269/referenceerror-state-is-not-defined

Comment: yes it is working but after going back it will not move to front again. Is this a correct way to handle this kind of case?

Comment: Added a plunker - https://embed.plnkr.co/tlO764Bm1nw9uecDKlLr/ cheers.That should be more then anoth now.

Comment: sorry but it work only one time , next time when i press arrow key it won't response

Comment: @sanu It does work like in the plunker. Please ensure you made all right.  Does it work so?